# Why does my Tarantool Cartridge retrieve data from router instance sometimes?

Tags: kubernetes, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I wonder why my tarantool cartridge cluster is not woring as it should.

I have a cartridge cluster running on kubernetes and cartridge image is generated from cartridge cli `cartridge pack`, and no changes were made to the those generated files.
Kubernetes cluster is deployed via helm with the following values:

https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBich/eebcf67786c36580b99373508f734f10

Issue:
When I make requests from pure php tarantool client, for example SELECT sql request it sometimes retrieves the data from storage instances but sometimes unexpectedly it responds to me with the data from router instance instead.
Same goes for INSERT and after I made same schema in both storage and router instances and made 4 requests it resulted in 2 rows being in storage and 2 being in router.

That's weird and as per reading the documentation I'm sure it's not the intended behaviour and I'm struggling to find the source of such behaviour and hope for your help.

Answer (score 2):

SQL in tarantool doesn't work in cluster mode e.g. with tarantool-cartridge.

P.S. that was the response to my question from tarantool community in tarantool telegramchat